# How to know true iPhone storage on iOS 11?

Tags: ios, storage

It’s clearly obvious that iOS 11 show overestimated device storage. This is a problem when I’m near out of storage. My iPhone is 32GB model, so iOS 11 shows 32GB capacity. But when I’m at 29GB, the truth is I don’t have 3GB available because the true storage is just about 29GB.

How do I see true storage size?

Comment: There's no 'proof' thar ios 11 shows overestimated storage so I'm not sure what you mean by that. Your iPhone has a **total** storage of 32GB and that includes ios itself.  There's dozens of questions and answers on this site that tell you how to view your **available** storage. Please [edit] your question to clarify what the exact problem is you're having including what you've already done to answer your question yourself.

Answer (score 1):

That is the true storage size, its just that App Data needs some space to fluctuate as you continue to use them. iOS is about 2GB total (average).